# Loading a script using a custom angularjs directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm very new to angularjs. 
I want to load a script tag using a custom angularjs directive. Below is the example code for what I want to achieve:

```
angular.module('app')
  .directive('myScript', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
       template : function(e,a){
           return '<script>document.write(5 + 6);</script>';  
        }
    };
  });
```

So, 11 will be displayed when the directive is added in html:

```
<div><my-script></myscript></div>
```

But I couldn't manage to achieve that. So, I guess my code is wrong? Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of the question below ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27533421/how-to-load-a-script-using-custom-angular-directive

Answer (score 0):

All right, why would you like to do it by a script tag, Yin?

You can you a built-in directive to do this.
Something like **ng-bind** or even curly braces **{{}}**
AngularJs will evaluate your expression and set the tag value as the result.

Example:

`<span ng-bind="5 + 6"></span>`

Result: 

`<span>11</span>`

Whenever you need to evaluate an expression you can do this way :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Carlos. Above is just an example. If the script I want to load is more complicated, how should I load it using directives?

Comment: Oh, got it. So, probably you would create a controller on your directive and use javascript to insert your script tag.
An alternative, you could use something like [ocLazyload](https://oclazyload.readme.io/) to get your script. :)